# jsonpath multiplication operation over entire object

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonpath

I have an object of the basic structure:

```
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 1
  },
  {
    "a": 2,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 2
  },
  {
    "a": 3,
    "b": 3,
    "c": 3
  }
]
```

All I need to do is programmatically multiply all the key values by `x` while keeping the structure exactly intact.

Example: if `x=10` then the result would be:

```
[
  {
    "a": 10,
    "b": 10,
    "c": 10
  },
  {
    "a": 20,
    "b": 20,
    "c": 20
  },
  {
    "a": 30,
    "b": 30,
    "c": 30
  }
]
```

I would presume that jsonpath is the way to do this, but I cannot figure out the proper query and the (postgres) [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-OP-TABLE) is very sparse on these details though it clearly implies that this can be done.

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model

Comment: JSON Path isn't the right tool for this. Have you seen [JSON Logic](https://jsonlogic.com/)?

Comment: Yes, I am well aware. Easier to say from the outside. The reason why a properly normalized data model isn't necessarily applicable is that the keys (a,b,c) vary constantly which forces the table approach into an area I don't want to go to. So I was making a strategic decision that if a simple JSONPATH solution existed, I could minimize the time spent converting the source data from JSON to tables just to do the simple math and then back to JSON again.

Answer (score 1):

JSONPath is intended for filtering input JSON tree, not for JSON transformations. It is literally an expression to guide processor to the elements of JSON to be picked for the output. The values in the original JSON or their aggregates can used to make filtering decisions, however, the output values are the unmodified source values. It is not possible to even reshape the JSON. It is possible however, to pick branches and leaves form the original tree that match filter criteria.

Consider using JQ instead

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/